# Different browsers, scrollable table

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, scrollable

http://jsbin.com/mivenohore/1/edit?html,output

I have created a table a table and it works wonderfully in Firefox.  When I viewed it in Chrome it had some issues and when I viewed it in IE it was unrecognizable.

I made some changes so that now there is just a slight problem in Chrome I haven't figure out yet (header not matching body with on columns - a pixel or two off) but the IE still has the problem that looks like the DIV is scrolling or at least the whole table is moving when all I want is the data in the table body to move the way it works in Firefox and Chrome.

Any input and advice is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should add additionals styles for olders browsers.
Use flex styles with prefixes -webkit- and -moz-.
You can check which styles needs prefixes at http://caniuse.com
i.e http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Can you give me some examples?  I see things best in code.  

Do you mean there are styles that say line up columns or do I need to add different ids for the same thing so older browers will understand them?

Actually, it wasn't an older brower problem mostly as IE 11 was the worst of the bunch.